# No process running but CPU usage is almost 70%

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

Can someone please help why my CPU usage is too high (70%) even if there is no process running?
In such a case when I run a process with 25% CPU usage gives an underrun.

[image: htop]

Ubuntu:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Hardware:
ASUS J18001-C

Edit:
CPU sorted all process including kernel

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `htop` defaults to not showing kernel threads.

Comment: so %70 cpu usage comes from kernel threads?

Comment: Maybe. Turn on kernel threads in `htop` to find out.

Comment: It is not kernel, most usage is %2, total %4-5

Comment: If not kernel, can you sort by CPU and see what rises to the top. I see VMware Tools (yes) and Gnome (yes) most frequently rising to the top. Total CPU very low.

Comment: The image loaded for htop shows already CPU shorted. I made cpu sort for kernel threaded also. max%2.

Comment: Okay. Is this a virtual private server? There are some processes running with suspicious names. Do you know all of them?

Comment: No, it is my own ubuntu. keylogger and lcd4linux is mine if you are mentioning about them but I dont know "exec" ones.

Comment: @DanielB do you have any opinion?

Comment: It’s probably malware. However, remote diagnosing this is hard. You could try finding the `exec-*` processes in the filesystem, for example using `/proc`, but how to go from there, I have no idea. Probably easier to just back up the current state (“offline”, not from the running system) and start from scratch.